# Rock Paper Scissors using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

[image: Rock paper scissors mock up]
 Whenever I click on rock - I want it to return what the Computer has chosen and the outcome of the round.
I'm still learning about DOM Manipulation - so what I've done is set up an Event Listener to #rock(ID for the rock element). The corresponding code:

```
document.getElementById('rock').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let a, b;
    a = document.getElementById('text');
    b = document.getElementById('rock').value = 'rock';
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        (b == 'rock' && compChoice == 'Scissors') ? b.textContent = 'You win! The computer picked: ' + compChoice : (b == 'rock' && compChoice == 'Paper') ? y.textContent = 'You lose! The computer picked: ' + compChoice : 'It\'s a tie! The computer picked Rock! ';
    }
});
```

The variable compChoice is set to an array - with 'rock', 'paper' and 'scissors' as its elements - and I have made use of Math.floor and Math.random to generate a random value from the compChoice array. 
So when I go to click on the fist - I will get the event to work once, but after clicking the fist once I can't seem to get a different result from what you can see in the image - basically the event doesn't produce a different outcome - only when i go to refresh the page it will produce something different. 
So my question to you is: How can I click on a button multiple times and have it produce a different result each time depending on the code above? (p.s. my apologies for the essay I'm new to programming :/)

Comment: The loop in the event listener doesn't look like it does anything meanginful, although that's not really related to the issue so far as I can see. It will just set the text content five times on click. Could you share the code where you select the `compChoice`? It sounds like you are setting it once and not updating the value.

Comment: ```let compChoices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
 let compChoice = compChoices[Math.floor(Math.random()*compChoices.length)]; ```

Comment: ```compChoices``` is set to an array. I've created a separate function called outcomes() -  for the different outcomes between what the player will pick and the random choice that ```compChoice``` will produce.

Comment: ```function outcomes(){
    let b;
    if (a == 'rock' && compChoice == 'Paper'){
        b = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Computer picked: ' + compChoice + ' You lose!';
    } else if (a == 'rock' && compChoice == 'Scissors') {
        b = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Computer picked: ' + compChoice + ' You win! ';

    } else if (a == 'rock' && compChoice == 'Rock') {
        b = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Computer picked: ' + compChoice + ' It\'s a tie!';
    
   ```

Comment: above this comment is the a small bit of the ```outcomes()``` function - ```compChoice``` gets selected and stored in the variable ```b``` where it's displayed on the text in the lowest div on the scoreboard.

Comment: The outcomes() function is then invoked in a function called ```playRound``` which stores the three Event Listeners associated with Rock, Paper and Scissors.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem - basically I stored `compChoices[Math.floor(Math.random()*compChoices.length)];` in a variable - which causes its value not to change unless i refresh the webpage. So instead I returned the expression in a function and it solved my issue.